# UserControl and Feature activation

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, user-controls

I have a sharepoint solution package with a Custom UserControl inside. When I deploy the .wsp the user control is placed in the CONTROLTEMPLATES directory. Is there any way to "delay" this step until feature is activated?
In other words what I would like my custom user control to be available only after the feature is activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. On deploy all the needed files are copied to the correct location. It is actually feature independant, because you don't even need a feature to deploy files. You will see that a feature is automatically created when you for ex. add a webpart to your solution. Not when you add a mapped folder.

What are you trying to achieve with delaying the usercontrol? What you can do is check in your usercontrol if a certain feature is active and adapt the rendering of your usercontrol accordingly. Ex. Show message that the feature should be activated before using the control.